# Resizing font in Code::Blocks

Tags: fonts, codeblocks, font-size

I've recently started using Code::Blocks IDE and am trying to get comfortable working in here.

Is it possible to change the font size using keyboard shortcuts, without the numeric keypad? I accidentally struck Ctrl+CapsLock and the font minimized.

Is there something similar to increase the font size?

Answer (score 20):

In codeblocks 13.12, you have to do according to the below sequence:

settings -> editor -> editor settings (press <kbd>choose</kbd>)

Here you will get font/font style/size...
Select your preferable size and press <kbd>ok</kbd>.

Comment: You are right: Changing the font or one of its properties will implicitly reset the zoom factor in the editor. But this is a quite cumbersome way if you are happy with your current font settings. So a **more direct way** is shown in [hewi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33791348/2932052).

Answer (score 10):

You should be able to just push <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> to increase text size, if not, look below.

To increase/decrease font size in the editor, you can either:

- hover with your mouse over the editor, push and hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and scroll mouse wheel up or down
- use the menu -> edit -> special commands -> zoom -> in | out | reset
- or you can install the code-blocks plugins for creating your own keyboard shortcuts, if none of the above will do by: console command: "sudo apt-get install codeblocks-contrib", restart code-blocks and in menu -> settings -> editor -> keyboard shortcuts -> edit -> special commands -> zoom -> in -> new shortcut -> ...

Answer (score 6):

For Mac, use Key **Command + Control + mouse Scroll (up / down)** to change font size.